# Bubble sorting not working for large file, but it works for small file

Tags: c, sorting, bubble-sort

I having issue with bubble sorting large data. This is an assignment, and my teacher explicitly said to use bubble sort to sort this large data. I tried running in a small file and it works perfectly, but it's having trouble outputting anything for big file. I don't know what's the problem. I have to use bubble sort too. Thank you. The small file "small.txt"is provided below. The big file "big.txt" does fit in here, it contains thousands of lines but the same format as the small file, and my program is provided below: I waited for 1 hour for anything to output, and the program is still in progress for the big file.

small.txt

```
FORD    2001
NISSAN  2000
JAYCO   2003
```

Program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *read;
    char lines[110000];
    int i=0, c, j,a;
    char *make[111100];
    char *year[111100], *swapyear, *swapmake; 

    if( (read = fopen("big.txt", "r")) == NULL) 
    {
       printf("can't open %s\n", "big.txt");
       exit(1);
    }

    c=0;
    while(fgets(lines, sizeof(lines), read)!=NULL){
       make[c] = strdup(strtok(lines, " "));
       year[c] = strdup(strtok(NULL, " "));
       c++;
    }


    for(j=0; j<c-1; j++){
        for(a=0; a<(c-j-1); a++){
            if(atoi(year[a]) > atoi(year[a+1])){
                swapyear = year[a];
                swapmake = make[a];
                year[a] =year[a+1];
                make[a] = make[a+1];
                year[a+1] = swapyear;
                make[a+1] = swapmake;
            }
        }
    }  

  for(j=0; j<=(c-1); j++)
    {
        printf("%s %s\n", make[j], year[j]);
    }    


 }
```

Comment: Perhaps the problem is simply that bubble sort takes a really long time, and your program just isn't finishing.

Comment: Error messages are important: `char *path="usorted.txt"; if( (read = fopen(path,"r")) == NULL ) { perror(path);}`

Comment: Just fyi, your bubble sort... isn't. You have no swap-detection. And you should be converting the year into `int` at the time of the file read, storing it in a native `int` array rather than repeatedly performing `atoi` conversion on the same data over and over (and over...) again.

Comment: For future reference, it helps to put a `printf` inside long running loops so that you can see progress being made. Something like `if ((j & 0xfff)==0) printf("%6d\r",j);`

Comment: This line: char lines[110000]; is where each single line is being read into.  I would suggest a more reasonable size, for instance, [30]

Comment: The code containing: strdup(strtok is not correct, because the return values are not being checked for error events.  Note: strdup performs an internal malloc, so before exiting the code, all those malloc'd areas need to be free'd

Comment: If you were to look at the statistics for bubble sort, you would notice that it becomes extremely slow, exponentially, as the number of entries increases beyond 10.

Comment: This mess:                swapyear = year[a];
                swapmake = make[a];
                year[a] =year[a+1];
                make[a] = make[a+1];
                year[a+1] = swapyear;
                make[a+1] = swapmake;  should be two sets of 3 exclusive OR operations.  Much faster, does not require any temp variables, etc.

Comment: This line: if(atoi(year[a]) > atoi(year[a+1])){ will be very slow and extremely repetitive.  Suggest using if( 0 < strcmp( year[a], year[a+1] ) ){

Comment: The declaration of the year and make pointers as separate entities means that the year will be sorted, but not the makes.  Suggest a single entity and have the comparison look at both fields as one long string.  This will simplify the code, but take more heap space and cause the call to strcmp() to take slightly longer, however; it will properly sort the whole file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This is the bubble sort algorithm. 
Note that it extends all the way through the data on each pass
(unlike the OPs code)
```

Step 1: Repeat Steps 2 and 3 for i=1 to number of entries to sort

Step 2: Set j=1

Step 3: Repeat while j<=n

```
     (A) if  a[i] < a[j]

         Then interchange a[i] and a[j]

         [End of if]

     (B) Set j = j+1
    [End of Inner Loop]

[End of Step 1 Outer Loop]
```

Step 4: Exit

and here is a code implementation:

```
for(i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
{
    for(j=0 ; j<n-i-1 ; j++)
    {
        if(arr[j]>arr[j+1]) //Swapping Condition is Checked
        {
            temp=arr[j];
            arr[j]=arr[j+1];
            arr[j+1]=temp;
        }
    }
}
```

The above uses a temp variable, usually a bad idea.
Here is an example of using the XOR operator (and no temp variable)

```
x = x ^ y  (1)
y = y ^ x  (2)
x = x ^ y  (3)
```

Comment: Are you actually advocating the xor trick? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm#Reasons_for_avoidance_in_practice